# Cycles Material Texture not showing in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

As the titles says. With a material like this one:

[image]

What I get is: In the "material" view, the texture shows up fine, mapped like I want it to be, but in the rendered view, it's rendered in an average of the color of the texture (it's not just black, I tried another texture, a wood one, and the result was a shade of brown averaged from the texture colors). As you can see, though, the preview of the material shows up fine.

Instead, with a material like this one: [image]

I get this: In the material view, the texture shows up but it's mapped incorrectly, BUT, in the rendered view, it shows up, but it's mapped incorrectly (obviously).

ALSO: I unwrapped another object (very roughly), applied the same shader as the first one (with coordinates set to UV) and the texture renders fine. What gives?
And, it definitely is an average of the color, because I even tried to draw some red stripes on the texture, because I thought that maybe the render was fine and it was some lightning quirk, but nope, non of the stripes showed up in the render.

[blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ak3fsuubr3jv3v/houseupload.blend)

Comment: Did you actually unwrap the first model?

Comment: Yes I did. Admittedly not very very well, but it's good enough for now. Good enough to show texture details and not a single color, at least.

Comment: Here the blend file (can't add it to the main) https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ak3fsuubr3jv3v/houseupload.blend

Comment: @Paul please pack the images in the file otherwise all we get is beautiful pink textures

Comment: Sorry, this is the texture: http://abload.de/img/brushed-metal-texture7eovs.jpg
I know it's not "mapped" to the UV, so it'll look warped, but I'm planning to do that later, once I solve this problem.

Comment: Basically the difference between the first and the second Material is that the firt uses a texture cordinate "UV" and the second "Generated"

Comment: It works fine for me on the objects which are unwrapped. Note that if you don't have a UV map for each object using the shader (some of your objects don't), UV mapped images will just be a solid color.

Comment: I know that. The problem is that the small object on the right, next to the wall, is unwrapped but still it shows a solid color

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your UV map is disabled.

Enable it in *Properties > Object > UV maps* by clicking the camera icon next to your UV map:

[image]

Comment: Yes! That worked, thank you! I don't even know how I ended up disabling that.

Comment: @Paul Welcome to the site :) [If this answer or any other answered your question, feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark above](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

If you UV unwrapped it, then from the Texture Coordinates node, connect the UV slot to the Vector of the Image Texture. I think that will do the trick. If not, try some of the other slots. I've had this problem a few times and most of the time I can resolve it this way, but not always.