# Materials not applying how the appear in preview (after rendering)

Tags: rendering, materials

So I've never tried using a texture before on a model but I was making a building and I wanted to give the door frames a 'limestone/marble' look to them so I popped in a texture and plugged it in from Image Texture to Diffuse to Output via color then BSDF ports. In the preview it appears like it came out good but when rendering my texture is a rather flat color similar to the texture I used. Image to show what I mean, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14114/599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to input some sort of texture coordinate for Blender to map the texture to your mesh. All image textures require this.

What you needto do is to go to the Node editor and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and add either a *Texture Coordinate* or a *UV Map* node.

[image]

Put one of the values into the purple *Vector* socket in your *Image Texture* node.

[image]

You can use any of these values, plug them into the same place as shown.

Comment: If the texture was appearing in textured view like the OP suggests, then they must have a UV map already (which would be used automatically).

Comment: Wait, what? Blender doesn't automatically use UV maps for me :-(

Comment: Huh? It always does for me..?

Comment: In cycles? I always have to add a UV or vector input.

Comment: Try this file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33723

Comment: It works . . . that is odd.

Comment: what version do you have ?

Comment: 2.49, 2.6, 2.70-2.73 and some others in between . . .

Comment: How recently was this functionality added?

Comment: It's been here since forever I think. IIRC the earliest release with cycles did this (just tested in 2.62, which is the oldest version of blender with cycles that I have around).

Comment: If no vector is connected, image textures will use `UVs` and procedural textures will use `Generated` coords.

Comment: Using a "generator texture coordinate" worked. Thanks a lot guys! It looks like the texture image is a bit large making it look odd but I can fix that. :D